# Is there be a new string object created for S.O.P?

Tags: java, string-concatenation

If there are two strings `string1` and `string2` contained in string pool referenced to String literals, will `System.out.println(string1 + string2)` generate additional string object in String pool as `string3=string1+string2;`? If not, why?

Like to add for more clarity how many objects are allocated in pool in such case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989261/does-concatenating-strings-in-java-always-lead-to-new-strings-being-created-in-m)

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
"string1" + "string2"
```

will result in a string constant

```
"string1string2"
```

created at *compile time* and added to the enclosing class's constant pool.

The expression

```
string1 + string2
```

where `string1` and `string2` are arbitrary `String`-typed variables will compile into executable code which concatenates two strings. The result is not committed to the pool.

Comment: and what about System.out.print(string1+"string3"+string2) ?

Comment: The entire expression must be a compile-time constant. The one literal between two variables won't make a difference.