# String concatenation: + operator with String literal

Tags: java

why `s3==s4` returns `false` while `s2==s3` returns `true` in line no. 8 and 7 respectively.

```
 1. String s="hello";`
 2. String s1="he"+"llo";
 3. String s2="hello"+123;
 4. String s3="hello123";
 5. String s4=ss+"123";

 7. System.out.println(s==s1);//prints true
 8. System.out.println(s2==s3);//prints true
 9. System.out.println(s3==s4);//prints  false
```

Comment: What is `ss`? Presumably you mean `s`?

Comment: You have a typo in your code you should use one s not two ss in line 5:

  String s4=s+"123";
Not:

  String s4=ss+"123";

Comment: String comparison in java should be done with the `equals()` method of the string class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does concatenating strings in Java always lead to new strings being created in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989261/does-concatenating-strings-in-java-always-lead-to-new-strings-being-created-in-m)

Comment: As nobody has found an adequate duplicate, I'm upvoting this.

Comment: @Bathsheba and why is my duplicate not adequate?

Comment: This question is more to do with compile time evaluable constant expressions.

Comment: @Bathsheba...yeah that is typo mistake.even on using s4=s+"123" ,s3==s4 returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s + "123";` is **not** compile-time evaluable so is not a candidate for string internment. (Note that if `s` was `final` then it would be.)

Therefore its reference will not be the same as `s3`, so the output is `false`.

The others all compare `true` due to string internment and the compile-time evaluabality of the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `==` operator to check the equality of Strings, it checks if the **location** of the Strings in the memory is the same.

In cases 2 and 4, the Strings "hello" and "hello123" will already be in the **String Constant Pool** (due to lines 1 and 3) and will be recognized as equivalent to those Strings, and will use the same place in memory for each. In simple terms, it will create a String object and plug it into both instances of "hello" and "hello123".

When you do:

```
String s4=s+"123";
```

At run time, it creates a new memory location for `s4`, since, the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) says that:

> Strings computed by concatenation at run-time are newly created and therefore distinct.

So, the memory locations are different, and hence it gives `false` as the output.